# Can't get .Net Embedding's objcgen.exe to convert my Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin.IOS project on Windows for my Xcode project on MacOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.ios-binding

I create a hello world Xamarin.ios class library project.
I add Nuget Embeddinator 4000.
I build it on Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.
But when I run objcgen.exe to do the Embeddinator conversion, I get the error below...

```
C:\Users\Doug\.nuget\packages\embeddinator-4000\0.4.0\tools\objcgen.exe --gen=Obj-C --platform=ios --compile --debug  --verbose `embedinnator2 class lib.dll'
Parsing assemblies...
        Parsed 'embedinnator2 class lib.dll'
Processing assemblies...
Processing: 1 assemblies
Processing Assembly: embedinnator2 class lib
Processing Type: embedinnator2_class_lib_Class1
TypeMapper Register: System.Void .ctor() init
        1 types found
Generating binding code...
Begin Generator
Generating Assembly: embedinnator2 class lib
Generating Type: embedinnator2_class_lib_Class1
        Generated: .\bindings.h
        Generated: .\bindings-private.h
        Generated: .\bindings.m
        Generated: .\bindings.xml
        Generated: .\embeddinator.h
        Generated: .\glib.h
        Generated: .\mono_embeddinator.h
        Generated: .\mono-support.h
        Generated: .\objc-support.h
        Generated: .\glib.c
        Generated: .\mono_embeddinator.c
        Generated: .\objc-support.m
        Generated: .\Make.config

Compiling binding code...

EM0000: Unexpected error - Please fill a bug report at https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000/issues
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Embeddinator.ObjC.SystemCheck.VerifyMono()
   at Embeddinator.ObjC.Embedder.VerifyDependencies()
   at Embeddinator.ObjC.Embedder.Compile()
   at Embeddinator.ObjC.Driver.Main2(String[] args)
   at Embeddinator.ObjC.Driver.Main(String[] args)
Debug Log:
Processing: 1 assemblies
Processing Assembly: embedinnator2 class lib
Processing Type: embedinnator2_class_lib_Class1
TypeMapper Register: System.Void .ctor() init
Begin Generator
Generating Assembly: embedinnator2 class lib
Generating Type: embedinnator2_class_lib_Class1
```

Comment: "Please fill a bug report..." - did you do this?

Comment: I plan to fill out Microsoft Visual Studio bug report today.

Comment: logging an issue on the Embeddinator github would be more effective